# Git: How to delete all untracked files?

Tags: git

I'm using Git for version control. Now I want to delete on my local machine all files in the repository that are not tracked.

I can use

```
git status
```

to list these files, but how can I delete all of them?

Comment: Cant you just check out all the files to a different place one your machine and then delete the old version?

Comment: For sure I can, but isn't there a simpler way?

Comment: See also: [Stack Overflow: How do I discard unstaged changes in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-i-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git/12184274#12184274).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you have it in ignore, use `git clean -xf`. You can do `git clean -df` but that will also remove un-tracked directories. Use `-n` for a dry-run.

See [cleaning up un-tracked](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/16/cleaning-up-untracked-files.html)

Comment: -x ignores the ignores..

Comment: `-xf` will delete ***and*** the ignored files and this is probably NOT what you want. Use `-nf` and proceed with care. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch

Comment: Remember, this may remove your environment/IDE folders (e.g. .vagrant or .idea (phpstorm))

Comment: **WATCHOUT!** gitignored files will be purged forever. -100

Answer (score 8):

```
git clean -f
```

Comment: It might make sense to add the meaning of that command to make this answer self-contained.

Answer (score 5):

***User interactive approach:***

```
git clean -i -fd

Remove .classpath [y/N]? N
Remove .gitignore [y/N]? N
Remove .project [y/N]? N
Remove .settings/ [y/N]? N
Remove src/com/amazon/arsdumpgenerator/inspector/ [y/N]? y
Remove src/com/amazon/arsdumpgenerator/manifest/ [y/N]? y
Remove src/com/amazon/arsdumpgenerator/s3/ [y/N]? y
Remove tst/com/amazon/arsdumpgenerator/manifest/ [y/N]? y
Remove tst/com/amazon/arsdumpgenerator/s3/ [y/N]? y
```

-i for interactive
-f for file
-d for directory
**Note:** *Add **-n** or **--dry-run** to just check what it will do.*

Answer (score 3):

There is a subtlety worth mentioning about `git clean -f` vis-a-vis untracked files and directories. If you have an untracked directory that contains files which are, a fortiori, untracked, then `git clean -f` will NOT delete those untracked files.

In other words, it is NOT always the case that `git clean -f` will delete all untracked files. A better explanation of `git clean -f` is that it deletes all untracked files that are *not* in untracked directories.

`git clean -f -d` *must* be used to delete untracked files that are in untracked directories and there appears to be no way to delete all untracked files *without* also deleting untracked directories that only contain untracked files.

Use `git clean -f -d -n` to REALLY see what you want to do to restore your working directory to what it would be without any untracked files. Then use `git clean -f -d` to do that.